# How to pattern match an object that extends multiple traits?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, traits

I have a super class `Command`, many different subclasses extend from Command and at the same time may also extend one or more of these traits `ValuesCommand`, `KeysCommand`, `MembersCommand` and many others.

Now I want to pattern match all implementations of `Command` that extend a `ValuesCommand` and `KeysCommand` at the same time.

Here is some **pseudocode** of what I want to achieve:

```
def apply(cmd : Command) = {
  cmd match {
    case c:(ValuesCommand && KeysCommand) => c.doSomething()
  }
}
```

I could fallback to match the first trait and nest a second `match`. But I don't really need it and looks terrible.

Comment: maybe better approach would be to override(or abstract override) `doSomething` method in traits `ValuesCommand` and `KeysCommand`? In this case you need not to perform pattern matching

Comment: I'd love to, but the code I'm juggling with is not mine: it's from a library that I'd prefer not to fork (Finagle Redis)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def apply(cmd : Command) = {
  cmd match {
    case c: ValuesCommand with KeysCommand => c.doSomething()
  }
}
```

When you have a class (e.g `ValKey` here) that both extends `ValuesCommand` and `KeysCommand` you also have something like

```
class ValKey extends ValuesCommand with KeysCommand`
```

Edit (Your comment):

I can't imagine a scenario where you want something like `ValuesCommand or  KeysCommand` in this case. You can read the link in @Randall Schulz comment to see how to get an OR.

Let's imagine you have your OR (v), like described in the link.

```
case c: ValuesCommand v KeysCommand => //soo.. what is c?
```

Now you still have to pattern-match on `c` to find out what kind of command it is. (most likely)

So in the end you can still do it directly like this:

```
cmd match {
  case vc: ValuesCommand => vc.doSomething()
  case kc: KeysCommand   => kc.doSomehtingElse()
}
```

Edit2:

For a scenario where you want to call your accept method on `cmd`, only if it is a `ValuesCommand` or `KeysCommand`, you can do:

```
cmd match {
  case _: ValuesCommand | _: KeysCommand => accept(cmd)
}
```

which, i guess, is more DRY than

```
cmd match {
  case vc: ValuesCommand => accept(cmd)
  case kc: KeysCommand   => accept(cmd)
}
```

Comment: In logic-speak, `with` is conjunctive. Both type identities must be present for it to obtain. What's a bit mind-blowing, at least at first, is that one can get unboxed, static *disjunctive* (either or, a.k.a. *union*) type composition in Scala! See http://www.chuusai.com/2011/06/09/scala-union-types-curry-howard/ for all the fun.

Comment: The `with` works perfectly and makes a lot of sense to me. But what about `||` ? 
EG:
case c:(ValuesCommand || KeysCommand) => c.doSomething()

Comment: I don't follow why the OR is a weird case: in that pattern match I would like to call the accept(cmd : Command) function either KeysCommand or ValuesCommand objects. I don't need to know exactly what part of the or condition has matched, since I'll be treating the object from now on as a `Command`. Of course your pseudocode using the "v" should omit the "c:" since you would refer at the object as cmd directly, I'd suppose.